# Best Dataset for Feature Selection using Simulated Anneling?

Tags: python, feature-selection, heuristics, simulated-annealing

I am working on Feature Selection using heuristic methods in Python, Can anyone tell me which will be best data set for Simulated Anneling ?

Answer (score 0):

The module Scikit-learn has a lot of datasets that you can find [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/). For Feature Selection there are some examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) but I'm not sure if that is what are you looking for.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: What do you mean by "best" dataset?

Comment: I mean Classification dataset with more than 200 Features and around 10000 features .